# jquery error with autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I got a function that looks like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

function getValues (fieldName, action){
            $("#" + fieldName).keyup(function () {
                if (this.value != this.lastValue){
                    if (this.timer) clearTimeout(this.timer);
                    this.timer = setTimeout(function () {
                        //$( "#"+fieldName ).autocomplete({source:"http://www.expat-job.com/ajax/" + action + "/keyword/" + $("#" + fieldName).val()});
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: 'json',
                            url:"http://www.expat-job.com/ajax/" + action + "/keyword/" + $("#" + fieldName).val(),
                            success:function(msg) {
                                //splitedmsg = msg.split(',');
                              $( "#"+fieldName ).autocomplete(msg);
                            }
                        });
                    }, 200);
                    this.lastValue = this.value;
                }
            });
        }
```

It is then called like this:

```
$('input').live('click', function() {

                var word = $(this).attr('id');
                var splitedWord = word.split('-');
                switch(splitedWord[1])
                {
                    case 'CompanyName':
                        getValues(word, 'cv-company');
                    case 'DegreeName':
                        getValues(word, 'degree-name');
                    case 'InstituteName':
                        getValues(word, 'institute-name');
                    case 'LanguageName':
                        getValues(word, 'language-name');
                    case 'CertificationName':
                        getValues(word, 'certification-name');
                    case 'SkillName':
                        getValues(word, 'skill-name');
                    case 'JobTitle':
                        getValues(word, 'job-title');
                }
            });
```

The ajax response looks like this:

```
["Mondial Assistance","Mondial Assistance Asia Pacific","Mondial Assistance Group","Mondial Assistance Mauritius","Mondial Assistance Thailand"]
```

It's an array wrapped in json_encode().

My problem lies in the autocomplete part:

```
 $( "#"+fieldName ).autocomplete(msg);
```

I have tried every way possible to input the data. I've echoed a string and split it to get an array.

I've used different syntax:
     $( "#"+fieldName ).autocomplete({source: msg});

I always get the same error message:

```
$("#" + fieldName).autocomplete is not a function
success()cv (line 453)
msg = "["Mondial Assistance","...l Assistance Thailand"]"
F()jquery.min.js (line 19)
F()jquery.min.js (line 19)
X = 0
```

After a lot of testing, I've found out that it works with a simple test like this:

```
$( "#"+fieldName ).autocomplete({source: ["orange","apple","pear"]});
```

So the problem is not that the function is missing or the library is not loaded or anything like that.

And now the question

Why?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're using the autocomplete widget is overly complicated -- the widget is actually supposed to simplify things for you. You DO NOT need to:

1. Invoke this widget on keyup/click events
2. Set timeouts
3. Make AJAX calls

Here is how you use it:

```
$("input.requires-autocomplete").each(function () { // add "requires-autocomplete" class to appropriate inputs
  var action;
  switch ($(this).attr("id").split("-")[1]) {
  case "CompanyName":
    action = "cv-company";
    break; // you need to add breaks
  case "DegreeName":
    action = "degree-name";
    break;
  case "InstituteName":
    action = "institute-name";
    break;
  case "LanguageName":
    action = "language-name";
    break;
  case "CertificationName":
    action = "certification-name";
    break;
  case "SkillName":
    action = "skill-name";
    break;
  case "JobTitle":
    action = "job-title";
    break;
  }
  $(this).autocomplete({
    minLength: 2, // widget waits until 2 or more characters are entered
    delay: 500, //  widget waits until 500 ms past the last keystroke
    source: function (request, response) { // specifying a URL that returns JSON/JSONP was enough
                                           // but in that case the server-side script must expect a query string parameter
                                           // "term" (text inside the control) and "callback" (for JSONP requests)
                                           // not your case so we do it manually
                                           // we call your script via getJSON
                                           // pass the text inside the control in the format expected by your script
                                           // and call the response funciton passing in the JSON data
                                           // the last statement is short-circuited by passing response as the second
                                           // parameter to getJSON, which effectively calls the response function
                                           // and passes in the response JSON data
      $.getJSON("http://www.expat-job.com/ajax/" + action + "/keyword/" + request.term, response);
    }
  });
});
```

If you strip out the comments and the switch-case logic, the remaining code is roughly 5-6 lines.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation :)
I'll just add a require-autocompletion class to those which needs it. Very elegant.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script> 

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 

 $( "#"+fieldName ).autocomplete({source: msg} );
```

You are not setting the source.

Comment: @user763228: From example I saw, an array passed as a parameter should be working.
I've tried with and without source option. I've literally copied your example and tried again.

No dice.

Comment: if you have created a string and not a array in the msg var try, $( "#"+fieldName ).autocomplete({source: msg.split(',')} );

Comment: Ok. I've modified the php script to return a command separated string and added split to msg.

The error remains:

response:
"Mondial Assistance,Mondial Assistance Asia Pacific,Mondial Assistance Group,Mondial Assistance Mauritius,Mondial Assistance Thailand"
error:
$("#" + fieldName).autocomplete is not a function
Line 453

Comment: Or use `$.getJSON` instead of `$.ajax`.

Comment: have you included the autocomplete jquery include? if it is not a function the script does not know how to use .autocomplete ... <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: It's not in my post but yes they are. I'll update my question.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QhQ9B/ - please confirm you are doing all this inside the document.ready function under jquery, how are you returning the data from the post call? as a string or array

Comment: Hi.

This website is awesome!

Your exemple is rather simple though. I managed to get it to work as well using a hard coded element id the way you do.

My problem is different.

I will try to reproduce it in jsfiddle and show it to you.

Nico

Comment: indeed, but some times keeping things minimalistic first of all proves that it does work, i just have a feeling that you are returning a json encoded array from a php script, my expirence of these when setting them to a var get set to a string so when you call var[0] you get a ret val of [ or something single char related.

Comment: @user763228: I tried both approach actually. I'm quite certain I'm doing something wrong. Others must have had the same problem as me.

To make sure the problem is not with the returned json encoded array from ajax, I've created a simple test:
fieldName.autocomplete({source: ["pear","apple"]});
It's in the getValues function, in the ajax success: call.

And it doesn't work.

I tried doing the same outside the function with a hardcoded id and even an ID set in a variable then called.

And that works. I'm worried it's just not possible to call autocomplete that way from a function (or something)